# Convert view xib to empty xib

Tags: iphone, view, xib

I have created a "view xib" but I want to convert it to an "empty xib" (Without of course removing the old xib and creating a new one). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure you can, just delete all objects you don't need from it - you can do that in IB's inspector window.